# How to use "asNavFor" option in ember-cli-slick

Tags: javascript, ember.js, slider, ember-cli, ember-addon

I'm trying to implement [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in my ember application i found this [ember-cli-slick](https://github.com/laantorchaweb/ember-cli-slick) via [ember observer](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-slick) and i have to use Slider Syncing option.in jquery its possible by using below option.but in ember how to refer the class name?

`asNavFor: '.slider-nav'`

Comment: you can define controller property named `breakpoints` for settings stuff like `'settings': {'asNavFor': '.slider-nav'}` and include that in `{{#slick-slider responsive=breakpoints}}` ..

Comment: @kumkanillam but how can i refer the class in {{#slick-slider}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install ember-cli-slick, run the below command

```
ember install ember-cli-slick
```

You can provide all settings to slick-slider through arguments like the below.

```
{{#slick-slider slidesToShow=1 slidesToScroll=1 arrows=false fade=true asNavFor="slider-nav" class="slider-for"}}
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg"> </div>
{{/slick-slider}}
```

I haven't tested `asNavFor` feature working or not. but that's how we need to provide settings to slick slider component.